# New DbContext objects are not created completely new?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I've been observing a very strange case.

```
foreach (var obj in objs)
{
     // a - unattached object
     DomainObject a = this.dict[key];
     using(var context = new DomainModelContainer())
     {
         this.SomeMethod(context, a);
     }
}

...
private void SomeMethod(DomainModelContainer context, DomainObject obj)
{
    // some code here with the query

    context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

After all I get an exception: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

I wonder if a new instance of DbContext is really new, and if not, how I can 'clear' it fully?

Comment: And what goes on in the `//some code here..` section?

Comment: Nope. You can see life cycle from the lines above: I call constructor every time before I call this.SomeMethod()

Comment: @podiluska There is a query there, like var companies = context.Companies.SingleOrDefault(...)

Comment: Something is evidently populating it then. Do you have lazy loading enabled, and referring to a parent entity?

Comment: No, lazy loading is disabled, and no, I do not refer to any parent entities. In fact, objects from the query and that in question are not related at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't managed to find an answer to my question above, but I have managed to solve the problem.

All what you need to do is to create a brand new object every time:

```
private void SomeMethod(DomainModelContainer context, DomainObject obj)
{
    // some code here with the query
    var newObj = new DomainObject() { Id = obj.Id };

    context.Entry(newObj).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

For some reason now it works fine.